# Why Group By clause is not working?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

Below is the code. I need the result date wise.

```
    Declare @tempInvoiceStatus TABLE
    (
        [InvNum] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
        [ExportStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
        [ExportFailReason] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [ImportStatus] [int] NULL,
        [ImportFailReason] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [ExportDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
        [InvoiceType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [ExportType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
    );

    Insert @tempInvoiceStatus
    select * from InvoiceStatus  where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ExportDateTime,10)  between CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@StartDate,10) and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @EndDate,10)


    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ExportDateTime,10)as ExportDate, COUNT(*) as Total_Records,
    (select COUNT(ExportStatus) from @tempInvoiceStatus I2 where I2.ExportDateTime=I1.ExportDateTime 
    and ExportStatus=1)as Success,
    (select COUNT(ExportStatus) from @tempInvoiceStatus I3 where I3.ExportDateTime=I1.ExportDateTime 
    and ExportStatus=2)as Failed
    from @tempInvoiceStatus I1 group by (Cast(ExportDateTime as DATE))order by ExportDateTime
```

I need the result date wise. Why am I getting the following error?

```
Column 'InvoiceStatus.ExportDateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the same element in `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` and in inner queries as in `GROUP BY`:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Cast(ExportDateTime as DATE),10)as ExportDate, COUNT(*) as Total_Records,
(select COUNT(ExportStatus) from @tempInvoiceStatus I2 where Cast(I2.ExportDateTime as date)=Cast(I1.ExportDateTime as DATE)
and ExportStatus=1)as Success,
(select COUNT(ExportStatus) from @tempInvoiceStatus I3 where cast(I3.ExportDateTime as date)=Cast(I1.ExportDateTime as DATE)
and ExportStatus=2)as Failed
from @tempInvoiceStatus I1 group by (Cast(ExportDateTime as DATE)) 
order by (Cast(ExportDateTime as DATE))
```

Comment: I tried, but even this is not working and throwing the same error as stated above. :(

Comment: Sorry, I missed `order by`. Try now.

Comment: Inner queries had the same problem... Sorry for so many corrections.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thankyou so very much. I was struggilng with this since so loooong :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `InvoiceStatus.ExportDateTime` to group by clause. The Columns should be same in `Select` and `Group By`. as You are using `ExportDateTime` and not `(Cast(ExportDateTime as DATE))`, you are getting the error.

```
 select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ExportDateTime,10)as ExportDate, COUNT(*) as Total_Records,
    (select COUNT(ExportStatus) from @tempInvoiceStatus I2 where I2.ExportDateTime=I1.ExportDateTime 
    and ExportStatus=1)as Success,
    (select COUNT(ExportStatus) from @tempInvoiceStatus I3 where I3.ExportDateTime=I1.ExportDateTime 
    and ExportStatus=2)as Failed
    from @tempInvoiceStatus I1 group by ExportDateTime)) order by ExportDateTime
```

Comment: It gives me this error.

The multi-part identifier "InvoiceStatus.ExportDateTime" could not be bound.

Comment: In the group by, specify only `ExportDateTime` instead of `(Cast(ExportDateTime as DATE))`

Comment: No, If I have two transactions on a single date, I do not want to show both. Writing only ExportDate time will grab be transactions on the same date, multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the column you want to specify in SELECT statement to have it in the GROUP..BY clause. So add the column **InvoiceStatus.ExportDateTime** to your GROUP..BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ExportDateTime,10)as ExportDate, COUNT(*) as Total_Records,
    (select COUNT(ExportStatus) from @tempInvoiceStatus I2 where I2.ExportDateTime=I1.ExportDateTime 
    and ExportStatus=1)as Success,
    (select COUNT(ExportStatus) from @tempInvoiceStatus I3 where I3.ExportDateTime=I1.ExportDateTime 
    and ExportStatus=2)as Failed
    from @tempInvoiceStatus I1 group by **ExportDateTime** order by ExportDateTime
```

Comment: I did not follow you. Can you brief a bit please.

Comment: In group by you can just use "group by ExportDateTime" insteaad of (Cast(ExportDateTime as DATE))